# Is crypto.stanford.edu spying on me?

Tags: browser

Using Firefox browser and I see in history that every time I log on to internet that crypto.stanford.edu is listed in history tab. What is this site and why is it in my history? Is this some kind of spy ware?

Comment: Is there a particular page it points to, or just the main crypto.stanford.edu site? Is there a specific name/title of the page?

Comment: Check out https://www.virustotal.com/en/ip-address/171.64.78.27/information/ and also http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: When I click on history screen display shows: 2016-05-17T01:27:38.647Z | Starting; will contact facilitator in 60 seconds

Comment: This is address bar copy.:    https://crypto.stanford.edu/flashproxy/embed.html?debug

Comment: It's a site you're visiting that's using bits of Javascript developed at Stanford to make your computer part of the Tor network... or something along those lines. There's more info about the project here: https://crypto.stanford.edu/flashproxy/ I can't tell you which site it is, but the javascript code **does** stop executing when you close the webpage that loaded it.

Comment: It's probably not a site being visited, but a browser extension.

Comment: @dobey You could be right, but I am 100% positive that sites can use the Stanford flash proxy javascript on their own, even if you have no browser extensions installed

Comment: Sure. I wasn't suggesting possibility, but probability.